# Polymer core elements aren't displaying for me

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

I'm trying to create a simple web-page using polymer/bower/webcomponents, that I downloaded from  [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/getting-the-code.html#using-zip). This is my html:

```
<head>
  <script src="../bower-components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/script" href="script.js"> -->
  <link rel="import" 
  href="../bower-components/core-component-page/core-component-page.html">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <core-scaffold>
    <core-header-panel>
      <core-toolbar id="navheader">
        <span>Menu</span>
      </core-toolbar>
      <core-menu>
        <core-item label="One"></core-item>
        <core-item label="Two"></core-item>
      </core-menu>

    </core-header-panel>
    <span tool>Title</span>

  <div class="content">
      If drawer is hidden, press button to display drawer.
  </div>

  </core-scaffold>
</body>
```

`main.css` looks like:

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#navheader {
  background-color: #56BA89;
}
.content {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

I'm hosting this with the python simple server.

I'm confident the imports are 'working' (insomuch as the server is returning `200` for all imports), so I don't think it's that. But the webpage looks like this:

[image: my webpage with broken elements]

This toolkit looks so simple, I just pinched code from [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/layout-elements.html#responsive-side-nav), and I can't see why it's not working. I'm on Chrome Version 39.0.2171.65.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import each element before you can use it.

```
<link rel="import" href="core-scaffold.html">
```

look at the source of https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-scaffold/demo.html for more details and examples or this tutorial https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-1.html

Comment: The version of polymer/bower/webcomponents (?) I have, doesn't have that html file (I used [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/getting-the-code.html#using-zip). Instead it has a `/core-component-page.html` file. I thought that'd have everything? Which should I be using?

Comment: I don't use the elements from JavaScript (only via Dart) so I don't know how to get them, but this might help https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/usingelements.html#using-bower

Comment: I'm on Windows in a restricted environment, so using bower has just been a pile of headaches. The zip and the download-via-bower should be the same, right? What do you mean by ' elements from JavaScript (only via Dart) '?

Comment: Dart has it's own dependency management and there is a Dart package available which wraps the JavaScript core- and paper-elements. This is what I'm using. Therefore I don't know how to get the source of the elements for a JS dev environment. Adding the elements to your HTML is mostly the same for JS and Dart therefore I thought I can answer your question, but I can't help you much with your follow-up question about how to get/install them.

Comment: That's the thing, from what I can tell, I've gotten them/installed them properly. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I thnk my problem is I've downloaded one setup and trying to run code for a different set up (Confusing!) I thnk if I had bower it'd be smooth. [This](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/usingelements.html#install) looks like the right link.

Answer (score 1):

I also believe it is bower_components, this is on my mac however:

I would advise using different text file for all your core components you plan to use.

Comment: I had them saved on disk as `bower-components` so the links are correct in my example. I changed them to `bower_components` just to be safe (in case there is some hard-coded link), but it's not changed.